# In iOS9, where did Newsstand go?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, newsstand, news.app

I have several subscriptions to newspapers that were in the Newsstand app.

But in iOS9 update, Newsstand is gone... and with it, all the magazines I had paid for, or was in the process of reading, etc.

Of course, they are nowhere to be found in the "News" app, neither in the "saved" tab not in the "search" results...

Where did they go, and what happened to my paid issues and my subscriptions?

This is making me freak out, since I was currently reading many paid magazines on the iPad, and I am currently updating the iPad as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Newsstand folder is gone but the apps should still be present just not wrapped in a folder. If you can't find them you can still re-download the apps through the App Store. Only apps that are removed to a legal reason can't be re-downloaded.

**Edit:**

> Individual Newsstand apps will now install directly to the Home
>   screen.

- https://developer.apple.com/newsstand/

Comment: What exactly do you mean "the apps"? You mean, each newspaper as an app? And where would they be present, scattered amongst other apps? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: @fabrice See my edit.